# Java bitSet starts setting bits from right to left or left to right?

Tags: java

if I set two different bits in a Bitset

```
  BitSet x= new BitSet(8);
  x.set(0);//.........Case1

  x.set(7);//.........Case2
```

In which case I m setting the most significant bit?

Comment: A bitset is not a number, it's a list of bits of equal significance.

Comment: The operations on a BitSet are performed by index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit set is not a huge number. It's a set (technically, a vector/list/infinite array) of bits. There is not even a method of `BitSet` converting it to a number.

Concerning the internal representation - that is implementation dependent. While an implementation could choose to store bit 0 as the least significant bit of the first integer in its internal array, that is not set in stone. I *think* the Sun implementation does this (except it uses an array of longs, not ints).

There is, however, a natural bijection between bitSets and integers. A bit set is intexed from 0 upwards, and any non-negative integer can be represented as a bitSet uniquely in a natural way as a binary number with the least significant bit stored as a bit 0. *Under this bijection*, bit 7 is more significant than bit 0, but for every bit in the bit set, each next bit is even more significant.

Answer (score 1):

**The LSB is index 0.**

*Example:*
Let's create the character `'a'` (binary `0110 0001`).

*Please note*: Adding the bits left-to-right, translates in running down from index 7 to 0.

```
BitSet bitSet = new BitSet(8);

bitSet.set(7, false);
bitSet.set(6, true);
bitSet.set(5, true);
bitSet.set(4, false);

bitSet.set(3, false);
bitSet.set(2, false);
bitSet.set(1, false);
bitSet.set(0, true);

// let's convert it to a byte[]
byte[] array = bitSet.toByteArray();

// and let's convert that byte[] to text now.
String someText = new String(array, Charsets.US_ASCII);

// this will print an 'a'
System.out.println(someText);
```

Which is the same as (JDK7+):

```
System.out.println((char)0b01100001);
```

Answer (score 0):

While the most significant bit is purely subjective for a BitSet, but setting both ends you could say one of them is likely to be the most significant, but you could say which one it was. ;)

If you want to set the most (and least) significant bit of a byte you can do

```
byte b = (byte) ((1 << 7) | (1 << 0));
```

or

```
byte b = 0;
b |= 1 << 0;
b |= 1 << 7;
```